# Image Gallery with Overlay and html inside cant overlay correct image. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-tools

Hi im doing a gallery where you have the litthe thumbs, each one select the main image, if you clic the main image you are suppose to get an overlay , inside that overlay is the picture and some extra html.

Ok I almost achieve the 90% of that code here http://jsfiddle.net/s6TGs/5/

Im using just jquerytools.. the problem is when you select second thumb... the Overlay you get is the Overlay for thumb1.. Even when i do change the respective (rel="#target") . So i guess im doing or missing something else..

Pls someone explain to me why even after the corresponding rel, is change, the trigger its always for item1.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the Script

```
$(function() {
$(".scrollable").scrollable();

$(".items img").click(function() {
    // see if same thumb is being clicked
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

    // calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
    var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");

    var relo = $(this).attr("relo");

    // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
    var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);

    // the large image from www.flickr.com
    var img = new Image();


    // call this function after it's loaded
    img.onload = function() {

        // make wrapper fully visible
        wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

        // change the image
        wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);
        wrap.find("img").attr("rel", relo);

    };

    // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
    img.src = url;

    // activate item
    $(".items img").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

// when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
}).filter(":first").click();
});

// This makes the image Overlay with a div and html

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("img[rel]").overlay();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok at least i finally get it work.. now i just have to build a NEXT and PREV button. but i will try until i really cant then i ask.. thanks anyway..
here is the code if it fits someones needs.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".scrollable").scrollable();

$(".items img").click(function() {
    // see if same thumb is being clicked
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }


    // calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
    var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");


    // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
    var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);
    var wrap2 = $("#mies1");

    // the large image from www.flickr.com
    var img = new Image();


    // call this function after it's loaded
    img.onload = function() {

        // make wrapper fully visible
        wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

        // change the image
        wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);
        wrap2.find("img").attr("src", url);


    };

    // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
    img.src = url;

    // activate item
    $(".items img").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

// when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
}).filter(":first").click();
});


// This makes the image Overlay with a div and html

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("img[rel]").overlay();
    });
</script>
```